# How to find available samaccountname using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a script which creates new AD users but there is 1 issue where there could be a chance the provided samaccountname already exists in AD. Thankfully a naming convention exists where the samaccountname's all must end with an alphabetical letter (A-Z). I'll need to loop through by amending the provided samaccountname with each alphabetical letter at the end of it to determine if the samaccountname and letter combination exists in AD and when one doesn't exist I'd like to set that to a variable so I can continue creating the new-aduser.

example: a123bcA,a123bcB,a123bcC,a123bcD etc...

Does anyone have any suggestions of what kind of loop, function, structure to use and how I can loop through it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you've worked out the algorithm to solve your problem. What are you requesting here?

Comment: I’m not sure what loop would be best to use or how to increment through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I don't have the same naming pattern as yours, so it's a little hard for me to replicate this example live, but I'd probably do something like the following:

*NOTE: Assumes you are using the ActiveDirectory Powershell Module*

```
$newUser = "a123bc"
# filter AD users where starting with new user name
$existingUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$($newUser)*'"

if (!$existingUsers.Count) {
    # user doesn't exist - start with A
    $newUser += "A"
} else {
    # sort the users by SamAccountName in reverse order, then take the first one
    # this will be the last letter used
    $lastUser = ($existingUsers | `
        Sort-Object SamAccountName -Descending | `
        Select-Object -First 1).SamAccountName
    # increment that letter
    $newUserSuffix = [char](([int][char]$lastUser.Substring($lastUser.Length-1))+1)
    # and add it to the username
    $newUser += $newUserSuffix
}

$newUser
```

This assumes no gaps in your naming scheme. If you're holding to your naming convention, this should work. Also, since I'm not trying to write production-level code here, it doesn't handle what happens when you run out of alphabet!

Comment: In other words, don't loop - get Powershell to tell you the last letter and choose the next one!

Comment: Thank you kindly for your speedy response and working solution! I've tested it and it works exactly how I want it to. Thankfully there won't be any instances where all 26 letters of the alphabet would be used. Thanks again and all the best.